# views attachment geoloc exposed filter

Tags: views

I am trying to create a list of shops using views as a html list and also as shop icons in a ipgeoloc map. Both these views will need to use post code taxonomy as its exposed filter field, I am having issue in getting the views attachments working. For me at a time only geolocation map is working or the html list is working. I am unable to get both of them working at the same time, I have attached the view correctly and have picked inherit filters for attachments

Like to get some guidance how this can be done, thanks in advance

Cheers
Vignesh